# How do you query ScriptDb for partial matches?

Tags: google-apps-script

I tried using RegEx and it did not return any results:

```
function findRecord() {
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var toFind = /Quality/i;
  var results = db.query({companyName: toFind});
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    var result = results.next();
    Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(result));
  }
}
```

From what I can see, ScriptDb's query() will only return exact matches for strings.

The only way I can see is to return the entire database and then iterate through it. I really hope there is a way to query partial matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ScriptDb currently doesn't support partial matches in strings. Depending on the data you may be able to use the [anyOf](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_scriptdbinstance#anyOf) method:

```
var results = db.query({
  companyName: db.anyOf(['Quality', 'quality'])
});
```

Comment: Thanks @eric. Need to search for 'quality' in a company name and come back with 'Quality Rancid Meats', 'Top Quality Shoe Shine', etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try iterating over the results using the match method

```
function testQuery() {      
  var db = ScriptDb.getMyDb();
  var results = db.query({});
  var start = new Date();
  while (results.hasNext()) {
  var result = results.next();
  if (result.companyName.match(/qual.*/i)){
  Logger.log(Utilities.jsonStringify(result));
   }
  }
  var endTime = new Date();
  Logger.log("time is " + (endTime.getTime() - start.getTime()) + "ms");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. You may open an "enhancement request" on the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

But depending on your usage, it may be possible to achieve your goal if you structured your database differently, probably creating some kind of "tag" category properties for your objects, that you set beforehand, i.e. when adding the object to the database, so you can query on it later.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The type of partial match I am thinking of is for company name -- this is not functionality easily replicated with partial matches.